# Copy column details from DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I've got a DataGridView which is bound to a DataSet being returned by an unknown-at-design-time SQL query (well, I know what the queries are, I just don't know which one the user has selected).

I allow the user to select a set of rows from the table and hit an OK button, and I would then like to copy those rows to a new DataGridView.

Naively, I used code along the lines of:

```
DataGridView_New.DataSource = DataGridView_Old.SelectedRows
```

This gives me a number of rows in my new DataGridView equal to the number of rows in `SelectedRows`, but the columns are not the columns from the SQL query (as they were in `DataGridView_Old`); they are, instead, the Row properties of each of the individual rows (DefaultCellStyle, Resizable, ReadOnly, etc.).

Is there any quick and easy way to simply grab the column data from `DataGridView_Old` and copy the selected rows into `DataGridView_New`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple method that might do what you need:

```
private void CopySelectedRows(DataGridView sourceDGV, DataGridView destDGV) {
    // Clean up any previous runs.
    destDGV.DataSource = null;
    destDGV.Columns.Clear();

    // Populate the destination DGV with the same columns found in the source DGV.
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in sourceDGV.Columns) {
        destDGV.Columns.Add(col.Clone() as DataGridViewColumn);
    }

    // Create a DataTable that has the same structure as the source DGV's DataSource DataTable.
    DataTable table = ((DataTable)sourceDGV.DataSource).Clone();
    // Use the data bound to the selected rows in the source DGV to create rows in your DataTable.
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in sourceDGV.Rows) {
        if (row.Selected) {
            table.Rows.Add(((DataRowView)row.DataBoundItem).Row.ItemArray);
        }
    }

    destDGV.DataSource = table;
}
```

My first impulse was to loop through the source DGV's SelectedRows collection but these are ordered as the user selected the rows, not necessarily the same as the displayed order.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in sourceDGV.SelectedRows) {
    table.Rows.Add(((DataRowView)row.DataBoundItem).Row.ItemArray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it. Had to batter my data load function into a compatible shape, but I should probably be grateful that your solution has inspired me to have carry that DataTable through to my second control.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will work with DataSets, but you could try using the [DataBoundItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem.aspx) property of each selected row to populate the new grid, something like:

```
public void Populate()
    {
        var selectedRows = GetRows(DataGridView_Old.SelectedRows);
        DataGridView_New.DataSource = selectedRows
                                      .Select(r => r.DataBoundItem).ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> GetRows(DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection rows)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rows)
        {
            yield return row;
        }
    }
```